# MySQL Stored Procedure Getting distinct count, displaying latest records only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count

I have the following inside my stored procedure that retrieves unique records from player names that have a faction of Neutral:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(DISTINCT Name) into @neutcount 
FROM 
   dim5players 
WHERE 
   Faction ='Neutral';

UPDATE dim5stats 
   SET Value = @neutcount 
WHERE 
   Function = 'Neutral';
```

This works find and dandy. The problem is that I have a field called Date as well.
I want to select the lastest date of the records to be listed in the count instead of a random record from the unique "Name" record.

This is a history table, and it records daily changes of the records, where Name can appear several times. I need to count only the latest records that have a faction of neutral with their latest records only. Some people change factions from time to time. I only care about their latest faction.

This is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `dim5players` (
`id` CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`rank_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`level` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`defender_rank_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Faction` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`Organization` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Date` DATE NOT NULL,
`Updated` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id`) USING HASH,
INDEX `name_index` (`name`) USING HASH,
INDEX `date_index` (`Date`) USING HASH,
INDEX `updated_index` (`Updated`) USING HASH,
INDEX `faction_index` (`Faction`) USING HASH
       )
      COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
      ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: pls show us the structure of `dim5players` table

Comment: also pls define "latest records"

Comment: Added structure. Latest Records are derived from `Date`

Comment: i mean what does "latest" mean to you? past hour? past day?

Comment: latest means the last DATE it was updated. The records are only updated when the records changed. Each NAME may have a different date depending on when the record was updated. So NAME may have been updated a day ago, while another was updated a week ago. The database does not change the date unless the record is updated because there was a change in certain columns.

Comment: I understand but when you said "I need to count only the latest records that have a faction of neutral with their latest records only" do you refer that you need to count the distinct names where date field is bigger the a particular date?

Comment: Just the latest date. In other words, I want the Last Updated record of each name. Yes, the 'bigger' date assigned to each name than any before on the same NAMES. Each NAME may have different sets of dates. I just want to count the latest date on each NAME that still holds the faction of Neutral.

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion with Michael i think i figured out what he needs:

1. "I want the Last Updated record of each name"

   ```
   SELECT  
       name ,
       MAX(Date) as last_date
   FROM 
       dim5players 
   WHERE 
      Faction ='Neutral'
   GROUP BY
       name
   ```
2. "I just want to count the latest date on each NAME that still holds the faction of Neutral"

   ```
   SELECT
       COUNT(last_date)
   FROM (
       SELECT  
           name ,
           MAX(Date) as last_date
       FROM 
           dim5players 
       WHERE 
          Faction ='Neutral'
       GROUP BY
           name
   ) as tmp
   ```

@Michael : Let me know if i understood you requirements correctly

Comment: wow thanks for your help. So close. Its picking the last date alright, but it doesn't pull the latest faction from the database. It still uses the data from older records, but does show the last date, even though the newest faction is not picked up. :)

Comment: well the faction is static like you said `Faction ='Neutral'`

Comment: The only field that is static is the Name column. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Everything else can be changed over time. Its the most recent change that counts.